# Event not exactly working (Inexperienced OP)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, contract-debugging

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract CustodialContract{

    address client;
    bool public _switch = false;

    event UpdateStatus(string _msg);
    event UserStatus(string _msg, address user, uint amount);

    function CustodialContract(){
        client = msg.sender;
}

    modifier IfClient(){
        if(msg.sender !=client){
            revert();
    }
    _;
}

    function depositFunds() payable{
        emit UserStatus('User has deposited money!', msg.sender, msg.value);

}

    function withdrawFunds(uint amount) IfClient{
        if(client.send(amount)){
            emit UpdateStatus('User has transferred some money!');
            _switch=true;
    }
        else{
            _switch = false ;
    }
}

    function getFunds() constant returns(uint) {
        emit UpdateStatus('Someone called a getter!');
        return address(this).balance;
}
```

I know this is not a bug, but my inexperience with Solidity is the cause of this. Anyway, I want to fire off the UpdateStatus('Someone called a getter!'). I receive this error on the Solidity VM.

(browser/Untitled.sol:38:14: Warning: Function declared as view, but this expression (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the default) or payable.)

I would like an explanation breaking down this error and suggestions on how to make the event fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the function `getFunds` is defined as constant but it contain an event emission just change it to `public`:

```
 function getFunds() public returns(uint) {
        emit UpdateStatus('Someone called a getter!');
        return address(this).balance;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Definitely helped thanks! I have to ask, is setting the function public or private good practice? Since just deleting the constant also allows the event to fire

Comment: Yes, these keywords define the visibility of the function, if you do not say anything it goes by default to public. If this answered your question please accept the answer.

Comment: Heh sorry I forgot about the button.